# How can I handle this one to many relationship with this contraint on a not PK field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, rdbms

I am not so into databases and I have the following problem. I am using **MySQL**.

I have 2 tables as follows:

1) **transfers** table:

```
CREATE TABLE transfers (
  id           BigInt NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  processed    Char(1) NOT NULL,
  providerpid  VarChar(16) NOT NULL,
  recipientpid VarChar(16) NOT NULL,
  symbol       VarChar(128) NOT NULL,
  `type`       VarChar(4) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ;
ALTER TABLE transfers COMMENT = '';
```

2) **annex1** table:

```
CREATE TABLE annex1 (
  id     BigInt NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  symbol VarChar(128) NOT NULL,
  doi    VarChar(256), 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ;
ALTER TABLE annex1 COMMENT = '';
```

I received the following requirement that seems pretty strange to me (but maybe I am missing something):

> The **annex1.symbol** values have to be a value have to be a foreign
>   key references **transfers.symbol**.

So from what I have understood it should be because I have to use JOIN with these 2 tables to obtain all the **annex1** records related to a **transfers** record (it is a **one to many** relationship).

But I can't create this as a **FK** constraint on **annex1.symbol**  because the **transfers.symbol** is not a PK.

Am I missing something? Can I specify in some way that the **annex1.symbol** must contain a possible value of **transfers.symbol**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

No necessary exactly PK, but you need index on `transfers.symbol` column, for adding FOREIGN KEY, something like:

```
create index ix on transfers(symbol); -- If this column have (and WILL IN FUTURE ALSO) unique values only, you can define this as UNIQUE index.

ALTER TABLE annex1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (symbol) REFERENCES transfers(symbol);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are  correct, you can't define relationship on non-key column but you can define `symbol` as Primary Key too in `transfer` table by means of `composite primary key` like

```
PRIMARY KEY (id, symbol)
```

(OR) define `symbol` as `UNIQUE KEY CONSTRAINT` and in that case as well you can have FK relationship on that column

Comment: In what table? in the transfers table?

Comment: What happens if a define it as UNIQUE KEY CONSTRAINT? It means that I can have a single record of the transfers table related to a single record of the annex1 table? Or what?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, No, UK on transfer table ... so transfer table symbol will have unique values but FK column need not. hope it helps

Comment: A last thing: but doint in this way can happen that into the annex1 is written a record with a symbol value that is not into any transfers table records?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, nope that's not possible ... that's why FK constraint. Give a try first and see.